# EF 0..1 to Many Relationship updates

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-framework-6

I can't get my head round this, threads all over SO state i'm doing all the right things but clearly I must have missed something ...

Given these two object defs ...

```
public class Invoice
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Block")]
    public int? BlockingCodeId { get; set; }

    public virtual BlockingCode Block { get; set; }

    ...

}

public class BlockingCode
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And then context with the appropriate relationship configuration ...

```
public class FaureciaContext : EFDataContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<BlockingCode> BlockingCodes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>()
            .HasOptional(e => e.Block)
            .WithMany(e => e.Invoices);
    }
}
```

Why when I do this ...

```
// assume this invoice has a BlockingCode relationship
var invoice = db.Invoices.First();
invoice.BlockingCodeId = null;
db.Savechanges();
```

Do I get this exception ...

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is
>   set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values,
>   a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be
>   assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be
>   deleted.

EDIT:

I thought I would add, as the answer here doesn't actually point out the real answer to the problem I had ...

It turned out that the reference in question was not the problem I was in fact updating another child property of the invoice class further up the code by something like this ....

```
invoice.Lines = MergLines(newVersion, dbVersion);
```

My merging code worked fine but as any keen EF user would know you can't simply "replace a child collection" like this, you have to remove the old and add the new as appropriate.

Comment: What if you did `modelBuilder.Entity<BlockingCode>().HasMany(e => e.Invoices).WithOptional(e => e.Block).HasForeignKey(e => e.BlockingCodeId)`.  At least that's how a similar relationship is setup in a DB first version I did.  SideNote: This is why I never do code first.  I prefer to setup the DB and then let EF figure this stuff out.

Comment: nope ... good call though :(

Comment: I suspect that `Invoice.BlockingCodeId` in DB is a foreign key constraint with not null.

Comment: Nope BlockingCodeId is nullable (see object definition above) and the db reflects that i nthe constraint defined as . 

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Invoices]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Invoices_dbo.BlockingCodes_BlockId] FOREIGN KEY([BlockingCodeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[BlockingCodes] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Invoices] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Invoices_dbo.BlockingCodes_BlockId]
GO

... when scripted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, reverse engineering this from what I assume is the basic SQL table structure you are working with...

Block Table:

[image: Block Table Definition]

Invoice Table:

[image: Invoice Table Definition]

And with a foreign key relationship defined between Invoice.BlockingCodeId and Block.Id...

[image: FK Relationship]

I get the following code-first entity classes and context when letting EF create them from the physical DB:

```
[Table("Block")]
public partial class Block
{
    public Block()
    {
        Invoices = new HashSet<Invoice>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
}

[Table("Invoice")]
public partial class Invoice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? BlockingCodeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Block Block { get; set; }
}

public partial class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext()
        : base("name=TestContext")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Block> Blocks { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Block>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Invoices)
            .WithOptional(e => e.Block)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.BlockingCodeId);
    }
}
```

When the entities and context are configured as above, the following code executes without issue and I see what I would expect in the SQL database:

```
var context = new TestContext();
var block = new Block { Description = "Block 1" };
var invoices = new List<Invoice>
                    {
                        new Invoice { Description = "Invoice 1" },
                        new Invoice { Description = "Invoice 2" }
                    };

invoices.ForEach(i => block.Invoices.Add(i));
context.Blocks.Add(block);
context.SaveChanges();

block = null;
var invoice = context.Invoices.First();
invoice.Block = null;
context.SaveChanges();
```

After execution, the resulting data state is...

Block Table:

[image: Block Data]

Invoice Table:

[image: Invoice Data]

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I would expect ... I think the error, being what it is, is not very helpful and the stack trace simply doesn't give me enough information to determine the exact line of code (I have likely identified the worng line) ... I think i'm perhaps looking at the wrong line of code and this confirms it. I doubt very much here that EF is at fault.